# Comparing a .TTL file to a CSV file and extract "similar" results into a new file

Tags: awk, grep, compare, comparison, gawk

I have a large CSV file that is filled with millions of different lines of which each have the following format:

```
/resource/example
```

Now I also have a .TTL file in which each line possibly has the exact same text. Now I want to extract every single line from that .TTL file containing the same text as my current CSV file into a new CSV file.

I think this is possible using grep but that is a linux command and I am very, very inexperienced with that. Is it possible to do this in Windows? I could write a Python script that compares the two files, but since both files contain millions of lines that would literally take days to execute I think. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit:

Example line from .TTL file:

```
<nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Algoritme>; <purl.org/dc/terms/subject>; <nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Categorie:Algoritme>; .
```

Example line from current CSV file:

```
/resource/algoritme
```

So with these two example lines it should export the line from the .TTL file into a new CSV file.

Comment: Please, post a few lines of both files and expected output.

Comment: Example line from .TTL file:<http://nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Algoritme> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Categorie:Algoritme> .

Example line from current CSV file:
/resource/algoritme

So with these two example lines it should export the line from the .TTL file into a new CSV file.

Comment: Got any idea? :)

Comment: How big is the TTL file vs. the CSV?

Comment: Both files are approximately 4,5 million lines long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk. First read the CSV and hash it to `a`. Then compare each entry in `a` against each row in the TTL file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }  # ignoring the case
       NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }   # hash csv to a hash
       {
           for(i in a)           # each entry in a
               if($0 ~ i) {      # check against every record of ttl
                   print         # if match, output matched ttl record
                   next          # and skip to next ttl record
               }
       }' file.csv file.ttl
<nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Algoritme>; <purl.org/dc/terms/subject>; <nl.dbpedia.org/resource/Categorie:Algoritme>; .
```

Depending on the sizes of files it might be slow and maybe could be made faster but not based on info offered in the OP.

Comment: I'm not experienced with GNU awk, so I'm going to need to take a good look at that. Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't this also be possible using Findstr by the way? I'm not entirely sure since that searches for a specific string, while I need to search for different strings each time. Both file are approximately 4.5 million lines long.

Comment: No experience with that, but in Linux you could `grep -f csv ttl` but it would be slower since for each record in csv `grep` would search the whole ttl so it would be n*m but above solution is about half of that.

Comment: Ah okay, then your solution sounds much better. Do you have any idea what runtime I can expect (approximately) using your method and with these two files?

Comment: None, sorry. Let us know, though. The future generations will profit from it (quantum computers and `grep`, you know :)

Comment: So I installed GAWK and am able to run AWK files from cmd now.If I run that it prints the correct lines I think, but how do I save those into a separate file?

Comment: Runtime update: Using your AWK script and these files I get a runtime of approximately 4 days (CPU: i5-4570 3.2GHz & 8GB RAM). It's still long, but much better than 20 days runtime using Python haha.

Comment: Not cool. Anything to know more about the data? Is there for example only one csv entry per one ttl entry so that we could delete used csv entries to free mem?

Comment: Hmm I could remove all duplicate lines from my CSV. It then has 787.087 lines instead of 4.426.542 lines. That would obviously speed things up by a whole lot. It's not ideal though, because I will be running a clustering algorithm on this data (and some extra data). So if a line appears multiple times that is important to know.

Comment: How do I add a counter to the AWK script that prints the CSV line number it is currently working on? Every 100th line for example? I tried creating a counter like in python (j=1 and in the for loop j=+1 and print j) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Duplicates from the csv are removed when hashing to a anyway.

Comment: Add `if(NR%100==0)print NR;` to the beginning of `NR==FNR{}` block.

Comment: Oh yes of course, forgot about that. Then I'm not sure what we could do to speed things up. There isn't 1 csv entry per 1 ttl entry unfortunately.

Comment: IGNORECASE of course takes its toll. Is it really necessary like in your example?

Comment: That counts the lines when it is hashing them right? I need some way to see how far the script is compared to the whole CSV list so that I get an idea of how much longer it is running.

Comment: Hmm ignorecase might not be needed, since lines in both files have the exact same spelling. So CSv might have "/resource/Android_TV" and the TTL file will have the exact same capital letters etc. Would that speed things up much?

Comment: Yes and yes. :D

Comment: Haha :D I removed the IGNORECASE = 1 and it doesn't seem to change the runtime.

Comment: Or did I do something wrong in removing that IGNORECASE? The first line of the AWK script now looks like this: BEGIN {  }.

Is it possible to force the AWK script to use multiple CPU cores? Since it now only uses 1 I think?

Comment: You can remove the whole `BEGIN` block as nothing is left there. Easy way to use multiple cores is to `split` the TTL file and run multiple instances of awk for the pieces.

Comment: Ah okay. How do I run multiple AWK scripts at the same time though? If I run the AWK using the CMD command (awk -f file input1 input2) then I can't type another command since it's still busy. Or can I just open multiple CMD's and run them in seperate windows? I have 4 cores so maximum of 4 AWK scripts at the same time I guess?

Comment: Yes, multiple cmds and if you redirect the output to a file, redirect them to different files and catenate the files later. I'd probably run 4 awks at the same time.

Comment: Great then I'll do that. Thank you very much for the help, you are amazing :D

Comment: Don't say that, yet. ;D

Comment: Haha well your idea seems to work, but apparantly my txt file contains a lot of lines that look like this:
"/resource/Register_(Windows"

This gives an error because it expects a ")" behind that. So I either have to manually add all those ")" or I have to automatically add them in Notepad++. I'm trying to figure out how to do this automatically with some expression but I can't find the right way to do it. 

So what I would need is: Find all lines that have "(" but no ")" and add ")" to the end of the line.

Comment: Make a new question in SO, post my code and samples of problematic parts.

Comment: Done! Here is a link :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753347/notepad-find-all-lines-with-open-parentheses-but-no-close-parentheses-and-add

Comment: Do you happen to know if forcing my CPU to have 100% load (when I run 4 of these AWK scripts at the same time) for about 24 hours will destroy my CPU? I want to run the scripts overnight and tomorrow during the day, but I am a bit afraid that it is going to overheat / destroy my CPU? I also made a post for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755415/running-several-awk-scripts-at-the-same-time-with-100-cpu-load