# Notepad++ find all lines with open parentheses but no close parentheses and add closer parentheses for AWK script error

Tags: regex, awk, notepad++, gawk

I have several large log files that include lines in the following format:

```
/resource/text_(moretext
```

Now these need to be closed with a ")", but the file is way too large to do this manually. Unfortunately the text within the lines can be anything. So I think I need some expression that is able to find all lines that have "(" and no ")". Then these lines have to be replaced with the exact same content but with ")" added to the end.

So it should look like this:

Before:

```
/resource/text_(moretext
```

After:

```
/resource/text_(moretext)
```

I feel like this should be possible in Notepad++ using regular expressions, but I have a hard time figuring out how to do this.

I need this because I am comparing these logs to a .TTL file to extract the lines that can be found in both files. I do this using the following AWK script:

```
BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }  # ignoring the case
       NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }   # hash csv to a hash
       {
           for(i in a) {          # each entry in a
               if($0 ~ i) {      # check against every record of ttl
                   print >> "testrunawk1.txt"        # if match, output matched ttl record
                   next          # skip to next ttl record
               }
            }
       }
```

Right now I get the following error on all these lines when I run the AWK script:

```
Fatal: unmatched ( or \(: //resource/text_(moretext/
```

Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Going to be off-topic if you do not show your efforts on it.

Comment: I just edited it a bit to include my AWK script and the error I receive. As for expression examples; I only managed to figure out \r to look at the end of the lines, but I can't figure out how to look for "(" specifically and how to ignore the text within the lines.

Comment: Concept seems fairly simple. Search for specific character followed by any other character(s) and append another character.

Comment: Using sed (with -E) or notepad++: `s/(\([^)]+$)/\1)/`

Comment: When i use your expression in Notepad++ it says invalid regular expression revo

Comment: Use the regex in pattern section: `\([^\r\n)]+$` and replace with `$0)`

Comment: That works partly, it now selects the correct line but also several lines below it. For example it now selects: "/resource/Riverside_(Suffolk_County
 /resource/Annibale_Caro 
 /resource/Valstagna 
 /resource/Bonobo.n3" 
So that first /resource line is the one I need to select, but not the ones after that.

Comment: I edited my comment.

Comment: Awesome that's it! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Oh wait, the replace does not seem to do anything. The search works correctly though

Comment: You're getting that error because you'e using the wrong syntax for your comparison and there's more potential problems with doing that than just an unmatched `(`. It's simply a bug in your awk script, not a problem with your input data. Since you've already accepted an answer to the question you asked, post a new question with concise, testable sample input and expected output to get the right solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed with -E option you could do:

```
sed -E 's/\([^)]+$/\0)/' file
```

With Notepad++ you can do the same with this difference that you should include newline character preferably with `\r` in character class.

Comment: Using your previous regex \([^\r\n)]+$ works to find the lines, but the replace $0) doesn't seem to add the ) to the line.

Comment: @Knarf I see this as an inconsistency in notepad++. Escape `)` after `$0`: `$0\)`

Comment: Ah yes that's it! One last small thing: apparantly all my lines have a space after them, so now it adds the ) with a space in between. Is it possible to remove that space as well? So for example now I get "/resource/Augustus_(uitgeverij )" and it should be "/resource/Augustus_(uitgeverij)".

Comment: Yes, search for `\([^)\r\n]+?\K\s*$` and replace with `\)$0`

Comment: If you want to remove trailing spaces off the line too just remove `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should get you most of the way there.

Find: `([^\(]*\([^\(]*)\n`

Replace: `$1\)\n`

In your find the unescaped brackets mark a group to be captured (the text you want to keep) which is placed in the replace by the `$1`

The `\` escapes a character so `\(` will pick up an opening bracket in the text instead of marking a capture in the expression.

Square brackets mark a set of characters to match with the `^` character marking that you want to match anything that is NOT in the group. so `[^\(]` matches anything that is NOT an opening bracket. This group is followed by a `*` which quantifies 0 or more matches.

Finally the `\n` marks a new line. This may not be the correct character for your line endings depending on the format. You may need to use something like `\r\n` instead.

I find a helpful resource for building regex queries is https://regexr.com
You can paste in a sample of your text and try out some matches.

Hope this helps.